# Installing plugin Contact Form 7 fails

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

installing contact form 7 for first time fails with message:Unpacking the package…  Installing the plugin…  Destination folder already exists. /web1/user25606/website/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/  Plugin install failed.

no sign of the plugin in the list of plugins? Haven't installed any plugins yet?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the folder is there already.
With your ftp client, browse to wp-content > plugins.
Do you see it there? then delete it and try again.

You can also download the plugin folder from the Wordpress plugin page to your computer and ftp it to the `wp-content/plugins` folder.
This way it won't give any problems because, if you already have the folder there, it will just ask you to overwrite and you can choose yes.

Answer (score 0):

Open directory, `wp-content/pluggins`. You will see `contact-form-7` folder. Delete and install again.